# Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be countinuously differentiable. Show that:

Tags: real-analysis, integration, integral-inequality

$$\left|\int_0^1f^3(x)dx - f^2(0)\int_0^1f(x)dx\right| \leq \max_{0 \leq x \leq1} |f'(x)| \left(\int_0^1f(x)dx\right)^2$$

here the exponents means the exponential and not the composition.

My attempt was very humble:

Mean value theorem:

$\int_0^1 f^3(x)dx = f^2(c) \int_0^1 f(x)dx$

this would simplify to:

$|f^2(c) - f^2(0)| \leq \max_{0 \leq x \leq 1} |f'(x)| \int_0^1 f(x)dx$

but this is hard to work on with

Comment: When asking questions, please include your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it.

Comment: I suspect it's not true if $f$ is allows to assume both positive and negative values.

Comment: @QiyuWen $f$'s image is on the non negatives

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f$ is non-negative, then
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_0^1(f(x)^2-f(0)^2)f(x)\,dx\right|&= \left|\int_0^1\left(2\int_0^xf(u)f'(u)\,du\right)f(x)\,dx\right| \\
&\leq\int_0^1\left|2\int_0^xf(u)f'(u)\,du\right||f(x)|\,dx \\
&\leq\int_0^1\left(2\int_0^x|f(u)f'(u)|\,du\right)|f(x)|\,dx \\
&\leq\max_{x\in[0,1)}|f'(x)|\left(2\int_0^1\int_0^xf(u)f(x)\,du\,dx\right)\,. \\
\end{align*}
Since $f$ is non-negative, by Fubini's theorem
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\int_0^xf(u)f(x)\,du\,dx=\int_0^1\int_u^1f(u)f(x)\,dx\,du\,.
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
2\int_0^1\int_0^xf(u)f(x)\,du\,dx&=\int_0^1\int_0^xf(u)f(x)\,du\,dx+\int_0^1\int_u^1f(u)f(x)\,dx\,du \\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^xf(u)f(x)\,du\,dx+\int_0^1\int_x^1f(x)f(u)\,du\,dx \\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1f(u)f(x)\,du\,dx \\
&=\left(\int_0^1f(x)\,dx\right)^2\,.
\end{align*}

Comment: the only weird part is that $\int f(u)f'(u) du = \frac12 f^2(u)$. Shouldn't there be a 2 somewhere?

Comment: @hellofriends Thanks. Fixed.